# What is "-lc++"?

Tags: xcode, macos

Anybody has any idea about what is this and how can I solve this build error ??

> ld: library not found for -lc++
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

thanks in advance.

Comment: random guess, `-lcpp`?

Comment: @MarcB `-lstdc++`, rather, as far as I know. [Edit: yup, just checked it.]

Answer (score 1):

Install libc++
You can download from:
http://libcxx.llvm.org/

Comment: do you mean Xcode 4.6.2 doesn't have libc++ included ??!
EDIT: actually I solved this error by choosing the LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler instead of the Apple LLVM compiler...