# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++

Tags: c++, clang

I am following a tutorial on building an audio classifier [here](https://docs.edgeimpulse.com/docs/running-your-impulse-locally) and when reach to the step where I run the sh build.sh I get the `cannot find -lc++` error.

Kindly, any advice on how to fix this error would be highly appreciated.

```
Building standalone classifier
mkdir -p build
rm -rf *.gcda
rm -rf *.gcno
clang -c -DTF_LITE_DISABLE_X86_NEON -Wall -I. -Isource -Iedge-impulse-sdk/ -Iedge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/flatbuffers -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/flatbuffers/include -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/flatbuffers/include/flatbuffers -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/gemmlowp/ -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/gemmlowp/fixedpoint -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/gemmlowp/internal -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/ruy -Imodel-parameters -Itflite-model -Iedge-impulse-sdk/anomaly -Iedge-impulse-sdk/classifier -Iedge-impulse-sdk/dsp -Iedge-impulse-sdk/dsp/kissfft -Iedge-impulse-sdk/porting -lc++ -lm  edge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow/lite/c/common.c -o build/common.o
clang: warning: -lc++: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lm: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang++ -DTF_LITE_DISABLE_X86_NEON -std=c++11 -Wall -I. -Isource -Iedge-impulse-sdk/ -Iedge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/flatbuffers -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/flatbuffers/include -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/flatbuffers/include/flatbuffers -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/gemmlowp/ -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/gemmlowp/fixedpoint -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/gemmlowp/internal -Iedge-impulse-sdk/third_party/ruy -Imodel-parameters -Itflite-model -Iedge-impulse-sdk/anomaly -Iedge-impulse-sdk/classifier -Iedge-impulse-sdk/dsp -Iedge-impulse-sdk/dsp/kissfft -Iedge-impulse-sdk/porting -lc++ -lm  source/*.cpp edge-impulse-sdk/dsp/kissfft/*.cpp edge-impulse-sdk/dsp/dct/*.cpp edge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow/lite/kernels/*.cc edge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/*.cc edge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow/lite/micro/kernels/*.cc edge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow/lite/micro/*.cc edge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow/lite/micro/memory_planner/*.cc edge-impulse-sdk/tensorflow/lite/core/api/*.cc ./edge-impulse-sdk/dsp/memory.cpp edge-impulse-sdk/porting/posix/*.c* build/common.o -o build/edge-impulse-standalone
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile.tflite:36: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is “-lc++”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302349/what-is-lc) (also the warning you put in the title is not the problem, but `cannot find -lc++` is)

Comment: @rustyx you are right "cannot find -lc++" is the problem but the title field didn'nt accept it as title!

Comment: @rustyx, kindly, what is the solution for the cannot find -lc++? I didn't understand the materials in the link you provided.

Comment: The solution to *this* problem is to install libc++. Your makefile seems to be full of other problems though.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I tried to install libc++ but didn't work.... it generated a problem ... link to new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640634/problems-with-installing-libc?noredirect=1#comment110776025_62640634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `clang`  by `clang++` or `g++`. Then `-lc++` becomes "automagically" linked.

Of course, spend a few days reading the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) (and of `ld` from [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/); since both `clang++` and `g++`  are running `ld`). Read carefully about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). The order of program arguments to `g++` (and also to `clang++`) are important.

Since you use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), you obviously need to spend a day reading its documentation.

PS. Budget perhaps a week of work in reading documentation.

Answer (score 12):

I think your build configuration is telling the compiler to use the standard c++ library from clang (LLVM).

That is a possible choice, and certainly not a bad one. However it is not the only choice for a standard c++ library. There are at last two commonly used standard c++ libraries: the very broadly used GNU standard c++ library [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/), and the slightly more modern [libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/). Both libraries are good. But since the GNU version is more commonly used (as of the time of this writing), you may run into less problems using this one instead.

To control the choice of the standard c++ library, the compiler flag `-stdlib=xxx` can be used. In your case, this flag seems to be set to `libc++`, or your compiler defaults to `libc++`.

Note that a common problem can be that the `libc++` development files are not installed along with the clang compiler by default. So it is well possible that all you need to do is to install the missing libraries, and everything will work.

You do have at least two options:

- Install the LLVM standard c++ library in case it is missing. On Ubuntu, with an upstream clang from llvm.org, you can install these libraries for example with (replace `15` with your actual version):

```
sudo apt install libc++-15-dev libc++abi-15-dev
```

- Choose a different standard c++ library. To use the more common GNU standard c++ library `libstdc++`, it is usually sufficient to remove the `-stdlib=libc++` flag from your build configuration, for example from `CMakeLists.txt`. It may also be possible that your compiler defaults to using `libc++`, in which case you would need to add the flag `-stdlib=libstdc++` to actively choose the GNU version.

Comment: clang invokes ld. After installing libc++-15-dev and libc++abi-15-dev my ld invocation was still failing because libstdc++.so did not exist. I was able to solve this with sudo ln -s   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so   Please consider adding this to the answer.

Comment: Dear @RemarkableBucket, it is a valuable comment about the symbolic link, thank you. However for me, linking used to work without that symlink. The package `libstdc++6` includes link `libstdc++.so.6`, and that was sufficient. Sadly, I can not currently reproduce if the setup still works. But at the time of writing this answer, it was sufficient. Since creating the symlink manually is also quite error-prone, I would kindly like to wait before recommending this, in case someone else can provide more insight...

Comment: understood, thanks 