# problems with installing libc++

Tags: c++, linux, clang

In reference to my original problem [cannot find lc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612405/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lc?noredirect=1#comment110772853_62612405) I tried to install lc++

```
sudo apt-get install libc++
```

But this showed me another problem about some held broken packages.

So, I am not sure if thats how to install the libc++ or even how to fix the held broken packages.

Kindly, any help hints on how to solve this problem is highly appreciated.

```
    sudo apt-get install libc++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcollada2gltfconvert-dev' for regex 'libc+'
Note, selecting 'libcaribou-gtk-module' for regex 'libc+'
Note, selecting 'libc6.1-dev-hppa-cross' for regex 'libc+'
Note, selecting 'libc6-powerpc-mipsr6-cross' for regex 'libc+'
Note, selecting 'libc6-mipsn32-x32-cross' for regex 'libc+'
Note, selecting 'libcmdliner-ocaml-dev-99zg7:i386' for regex 'libc+'
Note, selecting 'libcaribou-gtk3-module' for regex 'libc+'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-crypt-ctr-perl' for regex 'libc+'

 libcamlimages-ocaml-dev : Depends: liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev-il3k6
                           Depends: ocaml-4.05.0
                           Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                           Conflicts: libcamlimages-ocaml-dev:i386 but 1:4.2.0-1.1build3 is to be installed
 libcamlimages-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev-e0615:i386
                                Depends: ocaml-4.05.0:i386
                                Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                                Depends: libtiff-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: libgif-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                                Conflicts: libcamlimages-ocaml-dev but 1:4.2.0-1.1build3 is to be installed
 libcamljava-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                         Depends: default-jdk but it is not going to be installed
                         Conflicts: libcamljava-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.3-2build1 is to be installed
 libcamljava-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                              Depends: default-jdk:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                              Conflicts: libcamljava-ocaml-dev but 0.3-2build1 is to be installed
 libcamlp4-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                       Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                       Conflicts: libcamlp4-ocaml-dev:i386 but 4.05+1-2 is to be installed
 libcamlp4-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                            Conflicts: libcamlp4-ocaml-dev but 4.05+1-2 is to be installed
 libcamlpdf-ocaml : Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                    Conflicts: libcamlpdf-ocaml:i386 but 2.2.1-1build1 is to be installed
 libcamlpdf-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libcamlpdf-ocaml but 2.2.1-1build1 is to be installed
 libcamlpdf-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                        Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                        Conflicts: libcamlpdf-ocaml-dev:i386 but 2.2.1-1build1 is to be installed
 libcamlpdf-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                             Conflicts: libcamlpdf-ocaml-dev but 2.2.1-1build1 is to be installed
 libcamltemplate-ocaml : Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                         Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                         Conflicts: libcamltemplate-ocaml:i386 but 1.0.2-2build1 is to be installed
 libcamltemplate-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libcamltemplate-ocaml but 1.0.2-2build1 is to be installed
 libcamltemplate-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                             Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                             Conflicts: libcamltemplate-ocaml-dev:i386 but 1.0.2-2build1 is to be installed
 libcamltemplate-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                                  Conflicts: libcamltemplate-ocaml-dev but 1.0.2-2build1 is to be installed
 libcamomile-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                         Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                         Conflicts: libcamomile-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.8.5-1build2 is to be installed
 libcamomile-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: libcamomile-ocaml-data:i386 (= 0.8.5-1build2) but it is not installable
                              Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                              Conflicts: libcamomile-ocaml-dev but 0.8.5-1build2 is to be installed
 libccss-dev : Depends: librsvg2-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libcf-ocaml : Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
               Conflicts: libcf-ocaml:i386 but 0.10-4build1 is to be installed
 libcf-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libcf-ocaml but 0.10-4build1 is to be installed
 libcf-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                   Conflicts: libcf-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.10-4build1 is to be installed
 libcf-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                        Conflicts: libcf-ocaml-dev but 0.10-4build1 is to be installed
 libcloog-isl-dev : Conflicts: libcloog-ppl-dev but 0.16.1-8 is to be installed
 libcmdliner-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                         Conflicts: libcmdliner-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.9.8-2build1 is to be installed
 libcmdliner-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                              Conflicts: libcmdliner-ocaml-dev but 0.9.8-2build1 is to be installed
 libcompare-camlp4-dev : Depends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: camlp4 but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libtype-conv-camlp4-dev-c74s5
                         Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                         Conflicts: libcompare-camlp4-dev:i386 but 113.00.00-2build1 is to be installed
 libcompare-camlp4-dev:i386 : Depends: libtype-conv-camlp4-dev-ddkk8:i386
                              Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                              Conflicts: libcompare-camlp4-dev but 113.00.00-2build1 is to be installed
 libconfig-file-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                            Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                            Conflicts: libconfig-file-ocaml-dev:i386 but 1.2-1build3 is to be installed
 libconfig-file-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                                 Conflicts: libconfig-file-ocaml-dev but 1.2-1build3 is to be installed
 libcoq-ocaml : Depends: liblablgtk2-ocaml-il3k6
                Depends: liblablgtksourceview2-ocaml-rynx6
                Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                Conflicts: libcoq-ocaml:i386 but 8.6-5build1 is to be installed
 libcoq-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libcoq-ocaml but 8.6-5build1 is to be installed
 libcoq-ocaml-dev : Depends: coq (= 8.6-5build1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: camlp5-ps9p6
                    Depends: liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev-il3k6
                    Depends: liblablgtksourceview2-ocaml-dev-rynx6
                    Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                    Conflicts: libcoq-ocaml-dev:i386 but 8.6-5build1 is to be installed
 libcoq-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: coq:i386 (= 8.6-5build1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: camlp5-bskq5:i386
                         Depends: liblablgtk2-ocaml-dev-e0615:i386
                         Depends: liblablgtksourceview2-ocaml-dev-l26k1:i386
                         Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                         Conflicts: libcoq-ocaml-dev but 8.6-5build1 is to be installed
 libcothreads-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                          Conflicts: libcothreads-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.10-4build1 is to be installed
 libcothreads-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                               Conflicts: libcothreads-ocaml-dev but 0.10-4build1 is to be installed
 libcreal-ocaml-dev : Depends: libgmp-ocaml-dev-ah7j9
                      Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                      Conflicts: libcreal-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.7-6build8 is to be installed
 libcreal-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: libgmp-ocaml-dev-scq05:i386
                           Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                           Conflicts: libcreal-ocaml-dev but 0.7-6build8 is to be installed
 libcry-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                    Depends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                    Conflicts: libcry-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.2.2-2build2 is to be installed
 libcry-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                         Conflicts: libcry-ocaml-dev but 0.2.2-2build2 is to be installed
 libcryptgps-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                         Conflicts: libcryptgps-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.2.1-9build3 is to be installed
 libcryptgps-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                              Conflicts: libcryptgps-ocaml-dev but 0.2.1-9build3 is to be installed
 libcryptokit-ocaml : Depends: libzarith-ocaml-gqf85
                      Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                      Conflicts: libcryptokit-ocaml:i386 but 1.11-1build1 is to be installed
 libcryptokit-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libcryptokit-ocaml but 1.11-1build1 is to be installed
 libcryptokit-ocaml-dev : Depends: libzarith-ocaml-dev-gqf85
                          Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                          Conflicts: libcryptokit-ocaml-dev:i386 but 1.11-1build1 is to be installed
 libcryptokit-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: libzarith-ocaml-dev-rntd0:i386
                               Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                               Conflicts: libcryptokit-ocaml-dev but 1.11-1build1 is to be installed
 libcsv-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                    Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                    Conflicts: libcsv-ocaml-dev:i386 but 1.5-1build2 is to be installed
 libcsv-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                         Conflicts: libcsv-ocaml-dev but 1.5-1build2 is to be installed
 libctypes-ocaml : Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                   Conflicts: libctypes-ocaml:i386 but 0.7.0-1build2 is to be installed
 libctypes-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libctypes-ocaml but 0.7.0-1build2 is to be installed
 libctypes-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                       Conflicts: libctypes-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.7.0-1build2 is to be installed
 libctypes-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                            Conflicts: libctypes-ocaml-dev but 0.7.0-1build2 is to be installed
 libcuda1-340 : Breaks: libcuda-5.0-1
                Breaks: libcuda-5.5-1
                Breaks: libcuda-6.0-1
                Breaks: libcuda-6.5-1
 libcuda1-384 : Depends: nvidia-headless-390 but it is not going to be installed
 libcudf-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libextlib-ocaml-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libextlib-ocaml-dev-lk0a4
                     Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                     Conflicts: libcudf-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.7-3build1 is to be installed
 libcudf-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: libextlib-ocaml-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libextlib-ocaml-dev-9omj0:i386
                          Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                          Conflicts: libcudf-ocaml-dev but 0.7-3build1 is to be installed
 libcunit1-ncurses : Conflicts: libcunit1 but 2.1-3-dfsg-2 is to be installed
 libcunit1-ncurses-dev : Conflicts: libcunit1-dev but 2.1-3-dfsg-2 is to be installed
 libcurl-ocaml : Depends: liblwt-ocaml-wwm00
                 Depends: libresult-ocaml-ciso5
                 Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                 Conflicts: libcurl-ocaml:i386 but 0.7.6-2build3 is to be installed
 libcurl-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libcurl-ocaml but 0.7.6-2build3 is to be installed
 libcurl-ocaml-dev : Depends: liblwt-ocaml-dev-wwm00
                     Depends: libresult-ocaml-dev-ciso5
                     Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                     Depends: ocaml-findlib (>= 1.2.5) but it is not going to be installed
                     Conflicts: libcurl-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.7.6-2build3 is to be installed
 libcurl-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: liblwt-ocaml-dev-t5664:i386
                          Depends: libresult-ocaml-dev-ciso5:i386
                          Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                          Depends: libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386 (>= 7.15.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                          Conflicts: libcurl-ocaml-dev but 0.7.6-2build3 is to be installed
 libcurl-openssl1.0-dev : Depends: libssl1.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                          Conflicts: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
                          Conflicts: libcurl4-nss-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
                          Conflicts: libcurl4-openssl-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
 libcurl3 : Conflicts: libcurl4 but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
 libcurl4 : Conflicts: libcurl3 but 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-nss-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: libcurl4-openssl-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
 libcurl4-nss-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libcurl4-openssl-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
                        Conflicts: libcurl4-nss-dev but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.9 is to be installed
 libcurses-ocaml : Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                   Conflicts: libcurses-ocaml:i386 but 1.0.3-3build1 is to be installed
 libcurses-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libcurses-ocaml but 1.0.3-3build1 is to be installed
 libcurses-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                       Conflicts: libcurses-ocaml-dev:i386 but 1.0.3-3build1 is to be installed
 libcurses-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                            Conflicts: libcurses-ocaml-dev but 1.0.3-3build1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-compute-440 : Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-5.5-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.5-1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is  `lc++`,  you don't need to install it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install 'lc\+\+'` may work better if there is such a package.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, sorry guys, got so confused about it.... So, I tried the libc++ and the above error log is updated.... yet with the same error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, sorry guys, got so confused about it.... So, I tried the libc++ and the above error log is updated.... yet with the same error.

Comment: why do you need to install libc++ specifically? you can install build-essentials, it contains all you need to compile c++ code

Comment: @PierreBaret, build-essential is already the newest version .... also, I needed it because thats what my original problem in the other post.. it was telling me '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++'

Answer (score 1):

`E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`. You see, that right there is actually the problem. Your installation has broken packages. You need to fix the packages by running either `sudo apt -f install` or `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

After that you may run `sudo apt install lc++`. Also, `++` should not be any problem because `apt` (don't confuse with apt-get) does NOT support regexes. So something of the sort `sudo apt install mysql-*` is INVALID in apt (though `sudo apt-get install mysql-*` will work)

It would be better if this question were to be posted on [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I get this when I run your cmd line:
E: Unable to locate package or
E: Unable to locate package apt-get
E: Unable to locate package install

Comment: Gosh!!!! Those are either/or commands